# PHP header change issue

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, http-headers

I am using jquery mobile and php. My current URL is,

```
mobile/dashboard.php?mn=ce06ac9a87U0hFTFRFUlM-&shelterId=10
```

I am trying to change location by,

```
header('location: shelter/dashboard.php');
```

So, the URL should be like:

```
mobile/shelter/dashboard.php
```

Redirection is working fine. But, the problem is, it's giving me the previous URL in which I am passing variables (GET). When I refresh this page manually, then it's giving me mobile/shelter/dashboard.php URL which is correct.

Why do I need to refresh the page again?

Comment: Where is the `header()` code located in the context of your entire script? Conditionals that are in place may be affecting how it's being executed.

Comment: it's in my current URL page. And I am trying to redirect from that same page.

Comment: That much I understand. Try using an absolute URL in your redirect. I think what's happening is on the first redirect it's appending `shelter/dashboard.php` to whatever is in the URL at the time. If you visit `mobile/` then it gets appended correctly. So something like `header('Location: http://yoursite.com/mobile/shelter/dashboard.php')`. If that works, then that's your problem.

Comment: Are you sure that redirection occurs (once)? Can you see a 302 in Firebug or some other tool?

Comment: @Louis : I tried in using absolute URL, but still I am getting the same result.

Comment: @Michael Helwig: redirection is working fine, but url doesn't change until I refresh the page manually.

Comment: @user3067928 What makes you sure that redirection works? If you can't confirm the headers try to redirect to another page, e.g. Google, to make sure that it works. If redirection works, then maybe there is more than one redirection taking place which adds the parameters. Analyzing headers helps.

Comment: I have solved the issue: actually the problem was, I was accessing one page twice, and there is no need to do that. It was the flow of program, I have written wrong way. Thanks.